# State of Redux is says promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been trying to make work a very simple redux store but when trying to access it it says inPromise

Already tried to debug by using console.log() but im  not able to find the error

```
token = undefined state = {auth: Promise} auth: Promise {<resolved>: {…}} __proto__: Object


 const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{ console.log(state) return{ isAuthenticated:state.auth.token !== null, token:state } }
```

reducer creation

```
const authReducer = async (state =INITIAL_STATE, action) => { switch (action.type){ case actionTypes.AUTH_START: return authStart(state, action); case actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS: return authSuccess(state, action); case actionTypes.AUTH_FAIL: return authFail(state,action); case actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT: return authLogout(state,action); default: return state; } }
```

and root reducer

```
export default combineReducers({ auth: authReducer });
```

and store creation

```
const middlewares = [logger, thunk] const store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
```

Comment: Remove the `async` from your reducer. It's not needed.

Comment: Indeed. The 'async' function is literally returning the promise, and whatever that function returns becomes the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) will always return a promise. There's no reason you should have one on your reducer and you should remove it.

```
const authReducer = (state =INITIAL_STATE, action) => { ...etc }
```